# How to number the equations in Sphinx consecutively (Different rst files)

Tags: python-sphinx, equation

I have different chapters (e.g. Different rst files). I want to number my equations consecutively. For example in the first chapter the first equation is:

```
.. math:: 
  :name: eq.1

   W=W(I_1 (C)),I_2 (C)),I_3 (C)))
```

It appears like:

[image]

I have 4 more equations in the first chapter. The second chapter which is a new rst file starts with an equation as:

```
.. math::
  :name: eq.6

   F=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}
```

I want the number of the above equation to be **6** but it starts again from **1** as shown here:

[image]

How can I do the equation numbering consecutively with respect to the previous chapters?

Comment: It should work if both `numfig` and `math_numfig` are enabled: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-math_numfig.

Comment: Thanks. I added the lines: math_numfig = True and
numfig = True to the conf.py file and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbering works if the `numfig` and `math_numfig` configuration options are enabled (true).

See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-math_numfig.